# How to create cookies in website rather then browser?

Tags: php, cookies

I want to store the cookies in website rather then browser to access the same content on cross browser.
Please conclude your suggestion.

Comment: This isn't possible. New browser = new computer to your website.

Comment: As FrankerZ notes, the short answer is: you can't. The long answer requires a heck of a lot more detail about what you're trying to accomplish... But fortunately for you, the long answer has almost certainly already been written. I've provided several links for you to read; once you're done, the related questions on those will take you further still.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to login manually on different browsers but if you are using some database then you can store session data in your database. Actually you can avoid login by checking client IP (dynamic ip can be a slight problem) and comparing it to one in database if you don't worry about security.